# How do I fix "/usr/bin/python: No such file or directory" when entering an invalid command in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on Windows under Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL). When I run a command that doesn't exist in my bash terminal (for example if I accidentally add an extra s to `ls`), I get this error:

```
$ lss
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

The error's right, I only have python3 installed:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python3           /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch    /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema  /usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python3-jsondiff  /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer  /usr/bin/python3.6           /usr/bin/python3m
```

From previous use of Ubuntu, I remember that the message should be "The program 'lss' can be found in the following packages:" I don't need that message anymore and I don't want to install python2 just to get it working ([this question has answers for solving the problem by installing py2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942930/usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory)).

Is it possible to fix this without installing python2, symlinking python 3 as 2, or becoming perfect and never making typos again?

Ideally, I could port the "command doesn't exist" script to python3 or **disable it completely**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overriding the `command_not_found_handle` function ([a bash feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html)) with something that called `python` directly in my bashrc:

```
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
        # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
        if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1
           return $?
        else
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

This code is no longer necessary (was it ever?) and removing it fixed my problem -- now the old "can be found in the following packages" output again.

For completeness: If I wanted to skip the python code and simple output that the command doesn't exist, I could put this in my bashrc:

```
function command_not_found_handle {
    echo Command not found: $1
    return 127
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 is not a drop in replacement for python2. You need a python3 version of `lss`.

I would update `lss` if I was you. It is a stand-alone script and the source can be found on [github](https://github.com/mohsen3/lss/blob/master/lss). 1 is obvious:

```
print 'Usage:', __file__, '/path/to/dir'
```

"print" needs to use "(" and ")" when using python3. I would put the script in a file named `lss3` or something like that and use `python3 lss3` to find and fix errors.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. `lss` was a throwawy example. I'm talking about every single invalid command I enter. If I typo a command (like `lss` or `aptatude`) or use something that I haven't yet installed (`eclipse`), I get that error. On older versions of ubuntu, it would tell me what package to install to get that command.