# How to fix /usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to set up a subscriber and publisher in ros noetic on ubuntu 20.04 following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBtKo_pXrJQ&t=290s.

Where I am stuck is at 4:48 where instead of seeing the hello worlds, I see the error in the title. I have tried some of the solutions from here [/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942930/usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory) but have been unable to fix the error.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like he wrote all that using Python2, which was deprecated at the time he made that video (2018). `python` means Py2. Since then Py2 has been discontinues, and Ubuntu 20.04 uses Python3 instead. `python3` means Py3.

Comment: Related: [python-is-python3 package in Ubuntu 20.04 - what is it and what does it actually do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually)

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.